# TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I'm trying to push my data into this `CompareArray` but get the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
    at Object.addResult (src\services\CompareService.js:22)
```

**Code:**

```
this.addResult = function (type, result) {
    this[type.toLowerCase() + 'CompareArray'].push(result);
    this.checkToDisplayLinks(type);
    this.checkToDisableCheckboxes(type);
};
```

Comment: means `this[type.toLowerCase() + 
         'CompareArray']` is not defined

Comment: The [tag:angularjs] tag is for angular JS (i.e. v1), whereas the [tag:angular] tag is for Angular (i.e. 2+), so only one of the tags can be relevant. Can you please remove the incorrect one? (I believe that code is AngularJS, so remove the `angular` tag)

Answer (score 0):

Before you push anything check if it is undefined and initialized

```
if(this[type.toLowerCase() + 'CompareArray']){
 this[type.toLowerCase() +  'CompareArray'].push(result);
}
else
{
   this[type.toLowerCase() +  'CompareArray'] = [result];
}
```

Comment: um..... so the way it is written there would be no result added, I edited it so it will add the value when defining the array

Answer (score 0):

if you look closely, error is self descriptive.

```
Cannot read property 'push' of undefined at Object.addResult
```

addResult is your method. You are doing "push" on

```
this[type.toLowerCase() + 'CompareArray'].push(result);
```

for which it says - 'push' of undefined. which means

```
this[type.toLowerCase() + 'CompareArray']
```

is undefined. Push is a method only available on arrays.

Hope this helps.